# update parent timestamps when updating child model in polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, eloquent, laravel-5.1

in Laravel 5.1 I have two models.A city model and a Photo model.
there is a polymorphic relation between City and Photo.
While updating a city's photo with

```
$city->photos()->updateOrCreate($attributes,$values)
```

the child time stamps updates. but the parent model's timestamp , which is City in this case, does not update accordingly and I should manually call

```
$city->touch()
```

how can I update parent model's timestamp when touching a child model in Laravel?

Comment: If you want your pivot table to have automatically maintained created_at and updated_at timestamps, use the withTimestamps method on the relationship definition:

return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withTimestamps();

Comment: I'm interested in knowing the reason why you would like this behaviour? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For polymorphic relations

```
class Photo extends Eloquent {

  protected $touches = ['city'];

  public function city() {
    return $this->morphTo() // add this function if not already done
  }
}

class City extends Eloquent {

  public function photos() {
    return $this->morphMany(App\Photo::class, 'city');
  }
}
```

In this case, when the photo is updated, it touches his parent (city in that situation).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To update the parent's timestamp:

In your Photo.php model, you can declare the following line:

```
class Photo extends Model
{
   protected $touches = ['city']; //The 'city' refers to your parent's model
}
```

Now, when you update the photo model like what you did:

```
$city->photos()->updateOrCreate($attributes,$values)
```

It will, automatically update the timestamp of your parent's model which in your case, the city table.

Comment: Can you post your model codes? I have done the similar case and it works. Refer to this documentation about how to update the parent timestamps when updating child http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#touching-parent-timestamps

Comment: just change your answer from 'photos' to 'photo'. it should refer to child's model.and also this is for relationships where a models ``belongsto`` another model. I have a polymorphic relationship.

Comment: nope :) I just touch the model manually. tested your answers but no help. Any way, thanks you